# Spots on LCD of a Blackmagic pocket cinema camera

Tags: sensor, lcd

I bought a used Blackmagic pocket cinema camera last week. It was ok then I noticed a few green spots on LCD 3 days ago(bottom part), and today I noticed it grew bigger and also I noticed a new lines emerged top right.

What's this issue called? Is it a problem with LCD or sensor? Why it grows?

I ve been using Canon, Pentax, Sony DSLR cameras over ten years, and haven't seen anything like that before.[image]

Comment: Do the spots show up in images or videos?

Comment: @scottbb not really so I have been thinking it was an LCD thing. Though I can't understand why it grew.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that this is a problem with the LCD.

This might help you:
https://www.nelson-miller.com/what-causes-black-spots-on-an-lcd/

Here is also a video, I don't know if it is fake or not, but might worth a try:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F59mxBCW9Gw